# Safest way to rebase a public branch

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

What is the safest way to rebase a public branch - i.e. to cause the least amount of pain for everyone using it? Or is there a better alternative?

My team are new to using git & I've been asked to help tidy up their repository. They have a master branch which is very out of date & all work is being done on a branch called dev, (with branches off of dev for each new feature).

We've just released FEATURE_X and work has just continued on the dev branch on work for FEATURE_Y. I plan to merge all commits on dev up to FEATURE_X into master. The FEATUREs are big software releases - there are thousands of commits in both dev & master.

My problem is what to do about the dev branch:

1. Firstly I plan to merge dev up to the FEATURE_X commit into master, so the HEAD of master is at FEATURE_X.
2. Then I would like to rebase dev onto master, so effectively dev's commit history will start at the commit after FEATURE_X was released. I think this will tidy up the history of dev, making it less unwieldy to work with & make for less of a headache when FEATURE_Y is completed and dev needs to be merged into master again. From what I can gather, it's also not ideal to carry on working on a branch after it has been merged?

However all the advice I can find says not to rebase a public branch. We've got multiple developers already actively working with the dev branch to implement features for RELEASE_Y.

This article http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing suggests if you have to rebase a public branch, to let everyone know & to get them to use git pull --rebase
Does anyone have experience using this or is trying to tidy up dev more hassle than it's worth?

Comment: If you "know" all your users (i.e. they are all employees of your company) I would not consider the branch *public*. Communicate to your users what you will be doing (and why), when you will be doing it and what they have to do once it is done.

Comment: Thanks @SebDieBln, I'd always thought 'public' was any repo shared with others. I could tell all the users what will be happening, as everyone is new to git though, I'm keen to avoid issues so I guess the question is really, what should they do once the branch is rebased? Will a git pull --rebase sort their feature branches out cleanly?

Comment: Why do you think rebasing `dev` on `master` is necessary? I believe you could just merge `dev` in `master` when you see fit (e.g. at each release), and continue following a [Git flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)? or if you want to drop the `dev` branch, just follow a [Github flow](https://githubflow.github.io/)

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I would rename `master` to `legacy_master`, and be done with it.

If `featureX` represents what is currently running in production, I would create `master` there.

I would keep `dev` as is, and keep developing `featureY`.